# How can I limit Android tablet PCs from installing my app?

Tags: android, tablet-pc

I made the app which is optimized to support Mobile Phone. I don't want to support Nexus 10, Nexus 7, and other tablet PCs that have large screen. How can I handle that in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: read this: [supports-screens-element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explicitly declare in the manifest which screen sizes your application**

**Syntax**

```
<supports-screens 
android:resizeable=["true"| "false"] 
android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"] 
android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"] 
android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"] 
android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"] 
android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"] 
android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer" 
android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer" 
android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>
```

In your case :

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

After this playstore will show your app to devices except xlarge screen